# Swiping menus and modern web browsing

Tags: html, css, web, touch, workflow

Recently I've discovered that **devices such as** my **Surface** Pro 4 while browsing, with a **single swipe** from left to the right - go back to the **previous site**.
If I made a `<nav>` that responds to the same movement, how would I approach it to not load the previous page ?
Or rather shouldn't such a movement be implemented on a website anyway?
Personally I think that swiping menu navigations are great, so it'd be nice to find something that blocks the event of loading the previous page.
How I've created menus to this point was making them touch friendly for mobile & desktop (even though it has no touch support, so the user could just hold the LMB & drag).
I've **attached an image** of this happening if somebody doesn't have a touch device like mine. (the grey block on the left shows up if a user swipes)

So in summary:
Is it doable to turn this feature off for a user?
Should other steps be taken.[image: Attachment image]

Comment: I think this might come down to usability and what a user expects to happen (to answer your question). If the vast majority of devices switch to a previous webpage by swiping left to right, should you really be changing that (what the user expects to happen)? Does your reason to override said feature outweigh what the user expects? Often it does not.

Comment: I think it wouldn't get in the way, because the thing I'd want to do (hide a menu) would only happen if it was already open. And a second swipe would work as a normal "load previous". That'll be the best in my opinion.
But still I can't manage to find anything about the built in option.

Comment: Maybe, that extra swipe might cause more confusion than you would think. User expectations can be very fickle. Tread lightly and deliberately.